# how to read and write in a xml having same element name using java

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml with different number of elements like this.

```
<name>
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
</name>
<name>
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
</name>
```

I need to access the elements in java code.

Comment: Right, so use one of the *many* XML APIs available to you. Have you already decided which API to use? You could use the W3C DOM API built into the JRE, or you could use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) for example. Have you already tried something and run into problems? If so, show us what you've done so far and explain what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jaxb library from the standard jdk, thus you do not need to add other dependency to your project. Here is a good tutorial provided by Oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/